# what's the difference between summary and checkpoint in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py
I think checkpoint keep parameters, so why does summary keep parameters?

```
   train_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(train_summary_dir, sess.graph)
   path = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=global_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoints are used to describe state of the all the variables, constituting particular  model at a particular time. Checkpoints allow continuation of training in different session, restoring model weights. They basically include all the information except  the graph itself. While checkpoint are similar to summaries in a way, that both are serialized storages of model information, a typical checkpoint consist of 3 files

- `.index` stores index of variables,
- `.meta` which store graph information,
- `.dataXX`, storing actual variable values,
- and a text file `checkpoint`, keeping track of all checkpoint for particular training session
  So in general, checkpoint keep stores all the neccesary information to recreate the model and continue training, or just make evaluation.

Summaries are protocol buffers written to event files, saved in a directory. The are mainly used for Tensorboard visualizations. The allow real time observation of training process. Another difference is that summaries are in some way modular and can store anything from just scalars(which are just values used for inspection) to images, histograms graph visualization etc.
You can read this to know a little more about how the are created https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/board/wiki/How-TensorFlow-writes-data-and-read-by-TensorBoard
P.S. You can explore event files with `tf.train.summary_iterator` if you need additional analysis

Comment: I know Summaries are mainly used for Tensorboard visualizations. But ,What is the difference between the content of summaries and checkpoints ? Summaries contains graph, checkpoint also contains graph in *.meta file. Summaries contains graph parameters (such as w,b), checkpoint also contains graph  parameters (such as w,b)  in *.index and *.data file.

Comment: Updated answer, hope this will help